# python BeautifulSoup Wikipedia Webscapping -learning

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wiki

I learning Python and BeautifulSoup

I am trying to do some webscraping:

Let me first describe want I am trying to do?

the wiki page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks

I am trying to print out the

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="By_market_capitalization" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-controls="content-collapsible-block-1" aria-expanded="true">By market capitalization</span>
```

I want to print out the text: `By market capitalization`

Then the text of the table of the banks:
Example:
By market capitalization

| Rank | Bank | Cap Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JP Morgan | 466.1 |
| 2 | Bank of China | 300 |

---

all the way to 50

My code starts out like this:

```
from bs4 import 
import requests 
            
html_text = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
# text = soup.find('span', class_='mw-headline', id='By_market_capitalization').text 
Ak_soup = soup.find_all('section', class_='mf-section-2 collapsible-block open-block', id='content-collapsible-block-1')
print(Ak_soup)
```

I believe my problem is more on the html side of things:
But I am completely lost:
I inspected the element and the tags that I believe to look for are

```
{section class_='mf-section-2 collapsible-block open-block'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close to your goal - Find the heading and than its next `table` and transform it via `pandas.read_html()` to dataframe.

```
header = soup.select_one('h2:has(>#By_market_capitalization)')
pd.read_html(str(header.find_next('table')))[0]
```

or

```
header = soup.select_one('h2:has(>#By_market_capitalization)')
pd.read_html(html_text, match='Market cap')[0]
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import panda as pd 
            
html_text = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

header = soup.select_one('h2:has(>#By_market_capitalization)')

print(header.span.text)
print(pd.read_html(str(header.find_next('table')))[0].to_markdown(index=False))
```

###### Output

By market capitalization

| Rank | Bank name | Market cap(US$ billion) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JPMorgan Chase | 466.21[5] |
| 2 | Industrial and Commercial Bank of China | 295.65 |
| 3 | Bank of America | 279.73 |
| 4 | Wells Fargo | 214.34 |
| 5 | China Construction Bank | 207.98 |
| 6 | Agricultural Bank of China | 181.49 |
| 7 | HSBC Holdings PLC | 169.47 |
| 8 | Citigroup Inc. | 163.58 |
| 9 | Bank of China | 151.15 |
| 10 | China Merchants Bank | 133.37 |
| 11 | Royal Bank of Canada | 113.80 |
| 12 | Toronto-Dominion Bank | 106.61 |

...

Answer (score 0):

As you know the desired header you can just direct print. Then with pandas, you can use a unique search term from the target table as a more direct select method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks', match = 'Market cap')[0].reset_index(level = 0,  drop = True)
print('By market capitalization')
print()
print(df.to_markdown(index = False))
```